# How to loop over a value in a dictionary using elements in a list

Tags: python, list, loops, dictionary, for-loop

I have a list (let's say A) which has different visitor ids as its item

```
A=[1234,4650,8609,1675]
```

I have a dictionary which has the following key-value pairs

```
data = {"visitorid": "1234", "placement": "recommendations-ctr-airp"}
```

I run a predict retail API on the dictionary which will give product recommendations for the visitorID=1234.

The chain of code is as below:

```
from unittest.mock import Mock
data = {"visitorid": "1234", "placement": "recommendations-ctr-airp"}
req = Mock(get_json=Mock(return_value=data), args=data)
df = recommend(req)
```

The dataframe 'df' will be a combination of visitor Id and all the products recommended by the retail API for that particular visitor ID :

| visitorId | ProductID |
| --- | --- |
| 1234 | AA |
| 1234 | AB |

The problem that I'm facing is that how do I use list **A** to run the above chain of code to get the output for all the visitor ids?

Comment: Not really an answer to your question, but wouldn't `data` be more useful with the structure `{"1234": "recommendations-ctr-airp"}` ? Now for your question: what's the structure of the complete `data`  (holding all customers' ids) ?

Comment: @Swifty all the visitor Ids are stored in a list A. `data` is simply the collection of a single visitor id and what type of recommendation do I want to run on that visitor id.

Comment: You mean data["visitorid"] will change for each different customer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to execute code for every element in a list, a simple `for` loop should work.

Example:

```
A = [1234,4650,8609,1675]
list_of_dfs = []

for v_id in A:
    data = {"visitorid": str(v_id), "placement": "recommendations-ctr-airp"}
    req = Mock(get_json=Mock(return_value=data), args=data)
    df = recommend(req)
    list_of_dfs.append(df)
```

Then you have a list of the dataframes in `list_of_dfs`